# How to follow latest log file with tail -f?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a dir that saves a fresh log file for each run, so I use the following command to follow the latest log file:

```
tail -f $(ls -t | head -1)
```

So my question would be if there is any way to jump from one file to the next, if there is a newer log file available without having to stop the latest `tail -f` and rerunning it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for the answer, didnt see that question. Unfortunately my files have different names, so this wont work as it seems. Also I dont have a -F option as it seems. Do you have a alternative for that? PS: If this does not fit here I am happy to move it to SU, but I have found similar questions on SO, so I thought it might fit

Comment: What version of tail are you using?

Comment: How do the filenames look like where you have to make your pick from?

Comment: Something like this: `AAAAAAA199001010000.log` @kvantour

Comment: Dont know, but its an AIX system @StephenC

Comment: @MauriceNino do you have access to `inotify` or `inotifywait`?

Comment: @kvantour nope, doesnt seem so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could attempt is something like this:

```
# setup a link that points to the youngest file    
$ for f in *; do [[  ( ! -f last )  || ( "$f" -nt last) ]] && ln -sf "$f" last; done
# monitor that file continuously by filename
$ tail -F last
```

run the following in another shell

```
while :; for f in *; do [ "$f" -nt last ] && ln -sf "$f" last; done
```

You can also run this in a single command as:

```
while :; do for f in *; do [[  ( ! -f last )  || ($f -nt last) ]] && ln -sf $f last; done; done & tail -F last
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-F` flag for `tail` is supported in the GNU version.  (It is in the GNU CoreUtils collection.)

Apparently, IBM have provide download for the [GNU Toolkit for AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-overview), and apparently it includes a version of `tail` that supports the `-F` option.

You could use that in conjunction with the other answers to this question.  (For example, using `tail -F` with a symlink that you refresh regularly.)

Alternatively, if none of those solutions work for you, you could get hold of the GNU CoreUtils source code<sup>1</sup>, and modify the source for `tail` to do what you want, and build it yourself on AIX.

---

<sup>1 - I haven't checked, but I expect that the IBM devs will be contributing back any changes they make to CoreUtils to get it to work on AIX.  If not, they are obligated to make the source code available to you on request.  Either way, getting hold of AIX compatible source code should not be a problem.</sup>

Comment: The GNU tools usually compile cleanly on AIX out of the box; at least they did when I tried a couple of years ago. Anyways, the page you linked provides SRPMs as well.